# KeyTab in Java9

Tags: java, kerberos

In JDK8 one could make a keytab file like so:

```
static File a(String spn, String password) throws Exception {
    final File f = File.createTempFile("tmp_", ".ktab");
    final sun.security.krb5.internal.ktab.KeyTab ktab = sun.security.krb5.internal.ktab.KeyTab.create(f.getAbsolutePath());
    final sun.security.krb5.PrincipalName p = new sun.security.krb5.PrincipalName(spn, sun.security.krb5.PrincipalName.KRB_NT_SRV_HST);
    ktab.addEntry(p, password.toCharArray(), 1, true);
    ktab.save();
    return f;
}
```

In JDK9 this produces

```
error: package sun.security.krb5 is not visible
```

There is

```
javax.security.auth.kerberos.KeyTab
```

but [it](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/javax/security/auth/kerberos/KeyTab.html) appears to lack the ktab and password functionality.

What is the best way to make a keytab file in Java9?

Using a 1.5M sun.security.jar from JDK8 works but it not ideal.

Using [ktab](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/ktab.html) from ProcessBuilder is better but still ugly and ktab is not included in the JRE/JDK (8 or 9).

Comment: This is why one should not use the sun.* classes. They are internal to the JVM and as advertised can disappear at any time.

Comment: @RomainHippeau Yes I understand that which is why I am asking what the best alternative is.

Comment: Are you trying to do your own ktab.exe tool? Just wondering why you don't use ProcessBuilder/Process to execute it. In any case, the change in JDK 9 is that JDK internal classes are not accessible at compile-time. You'll read more about this in the JDK 9 documentation and release notes.

Comment: @AlanBateman ProcessBuilder an option it just seems silly to instantiate a whole new Process when they could have just exposed some methods... and ktab is not in the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

The API you were using is internal to JRE. You can use alternative Kerberos implementation from [Apache Kerby](http://directory.apache.org/kerby/) project. See [KeytabAddCommand](https://github.com/apache/directory-kerby/blob/trunk/kerby-tool/kdc-tool/src/main/java/org/apache/kerby/kerberos/tool/kadmin/command/KeytabAddCommand.java) for an example.

Comment: That's not going to work with JDK17 https://github.com/apache/directory-kerby/blob/trunk/has-project/has-common/src/main/java/org/apache/kerby/has/common/spnego/KerberosUtil.java#L86